# Download HLS content not start

Tags: ios, swift, download, http-live-streaming

I followed the [Media Playback Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/MediaPlaybackGuide/Contents/Resources/en.lproj/HTTPLiveStreaming/HTTPLiveStreaming.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016757-CH11-SW9) from Apple to download HLS content. The following implementation usually works fine, but, occasionally, and with no apparent reason, just stop working. Delegate methods won't report anything, neither download progress, nor error. Download just refuse to start. When this happens, in order to start download again, the only way is rebooting the device. Is there anyone facing the same problem? Could someone point me on how to fix this?

```
func setupAssetDownload() {

    // Create new background session configuration.
    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: "Player")
    configuration.isDiscretionary = true
    configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 300


    // Create a new AVAssetDownloadURLSession with background configuration, delegate, and queue
    downloadSession = AVAssetDownloadURLSession(configuration: configuration,
                                                assetDownloadDelegate: self,
                                                delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main)
}
```

Create and configure the download session:

```
func assetDownload(for item: DownloadItem) {

    let asset = AVURLAsset(url: item.url)

    asset.resourceLoader.preloadsEligibleContentKeys = true
    asset.resourceLoader.setDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default))


    // Create new AVAssetDownloadTask for the desired asset
    guard let task = downloadSession.makeAssetDownloadTask(asset: asset,
                                                           assetTitle: item.title!,
                                                           assetArtworkData: data,
                                                           options: [AVAssetDownloadTaskMinimumRequiredMediaBitrateKey: 2_787_000])
        else {
            status[item.url!] = .error
            return
    }

    task.taskDescription = item.title!

    // Start task and begin download
    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: Hello. Have you figure out what cause that weird behavior?